# Retrieve results of a stored procedure on c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have a stored procedure that selects and returns a list of years. In sql server I call it like this:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[TestName]
        @del= 0

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

In order to receive the list.

My SP looks like this:

```
USE [TestTable]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestName] (@delvarchar(7))

AS
BEGIN

                    SELECT   YEAR(  [added]) AS year FROM [MyTable]


                    GROUP BY  YEAR(  [added]) 
                    ORDER BY  YEAR(  [added])  DESC

END
```

I want to do the same from c# though and pass the values in a List.

What I am trying is:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("TestName", conn)
{
   CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
})
{
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@del", del);
   SqlParameter retval = command.Parameters.Add("@return_value", SqlDbType.VarChar);
   retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   int retunvalue = (int)command.Parameters["@return_value"].Value;
   conn.Close();

   return retunvalue;
}
```

This does not return any values though, instead it only returns `0`. What am I doing wrong and how can I get the list inside a variable as specified?

Editing the code following John Hanna's advise I have something like this:

```
        public List<string> getYears(string constr, int del)
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(constr))
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("TestName", conn)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            })
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@del", del);
                List<string> retunvalue = new List<string>();
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader;
                reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                conn.Close();

                return retunvalue;
            }
        }
```

And by adding a breakpoint in order to explore `reader` I see that it is only contains errors:

`Depth = '(reader).Depth' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'`

As for Krishna's answer, `dtList` was empty with a count of 0, and I am not sure how to implement Badhon's suggestion.

Comment: That C# code looks correct for reading a return value. You should post the SP as well as the problem might be in there (e.g. you might be returning the value using SELECT instead of RETURN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` is so called because its for use with something that doesn't *query* the data. The `0` you get back is the number of rows the command changed.

Instead use `ExecuteReader()` and you will get back a `SqlDataReader` object that you can call `Read()` on to move through rows and then examine the details of each.

If you want to return that to another method use `ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)` and then rather than `Close()` or `Dispose()` the connection after you are finished, `Close()` or `Dispose()` the reader and that will close the connection then.

If you only have one row with one column (or for some reason only care about the first column of the first row even though there is more), then `ExecuteScalar()` is a convenient way to get just that single value.

Comment: Hi Jon, I edited my question including what I got by trying your suggestion.

Comment: My suggestion did include calling `Read()` on it too. Keep calling `Read()` until it returns false. After each call that returns true get the values for that row.

Comment: Indeed I should have been more careful.

Comment: One more thing. Should I do `reader.Close();` or close the connection instead?

Comment: If you use the reader within the method then just close the connection. However if you need to return a reader then don't close the connection (don't use `using`) but use the overload `.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)`. When the calling method is finished with the reader it should close it, and it will close the connection too.

Comment: Is it possible that this exact method wont ever have a true value in some cases. I am trying the same thing this time for a SP that is more complex and I never get inside the `while` loop.

Comment: `Read()` will immediately return `false` if the resultset was empty.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use ExecuteNonQuery, rather use ExecuteDataSet as follow:

```
public List<DSM_DocPropIdentify> GetDocPropIdentify(string docPropIdentifyID, string action, out string errorNumber)
    {
        errorNumber = string.Empty;
        List<DSM_DocPropIdentify> docPropIdentifyList = new List<DSM_DocPropIdentify>();
        DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
        SqlDatabase db = factory.CreateDefault() as SqlDatabase;
        using (DbCommand dbCommandWrapper = db.GetStoredProcCommand("GetDocPropIdentify"))
        {
            // Set parameters 
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommandWrapper, "@DocPropIdentifyID", SqlDbType.VarChar, docPropIdentifyID);
            db.AddOutParameter(dbCommandWrapper, spStatusParam, DbType.String, 10);
            // Execute SP.
            DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommandWrapper);

            if (!db.GetParameterValue(dbCommandWrapper, spStatusParam).IsNullOrZero())
            {
                // Get the error number, if error occurred.
                errorNumber = db.GetParameterValue(dbCommandWrapper, spStatusParam).PrefixErrorCode();
            }
            else
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
                    docPropIdentifyList = dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(reader => new DSM_DocPropIdentify
                    {
                        DocPropIdentifyID = reader.GetString("DocPropIdentifyID"),
                        DocPropertyID = reader.GetString("DocPropertyID"),
                        DocCategoryID = reader.GetString("DocCategoryID"),
                        DocTypeID = reader.GetString("DocTypeID"),
                        OwnerID = reader.GetString("OwnerID"),
                        IdentificationCode = reader.GetString("IdentificationCode"),
                        IdentificationSL = reader.GetString("IdentificationSL"),
                        AttributeGroup = reader.GetString("AttributeGroup"),
                        IdentificationAttribute = reader.GetString("IdentificationAttribute"),
                        IsRequired = reader.GetInt16("IsRequired"),
                        IsAuto = reader.GetInt16("IsAuto"),
                        SetOn = reader.GetString("SetOn"),
                        SetBy = reader.GetString("SetBy"),
                        ModifiedOn = reader.GetString("ModifiedOn"),
                        ModifiedBy = reader.GetString("ModifiedBy"),
                        Status = reader.GetInt32("Status"),
                        Remarks = reader.GetString("Remarks")
                    }).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
        return docPropIdentifyList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is dbo.TestName returns you a table or a value. If that returns you a table, then you would have to execute DataAdapter or execute DataReader. You should replace the above statement 
as

```
DataTable dtList=new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adapter=new SqlDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand=command;
adapter.Fill(dtList);
```

Then you can iterate through the datatable and add that to your list

```
List<Object> listObj=new List<Object>();
foreach(var rows in dtList.Rows)
{
    listObj.Add(rows["Column_name"]);
}
```

I analysed your query, and found that, the statement

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[TestName]
        @del= 0

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

returns multiple tables. You can remove the last statement which is redundant.

```
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

The datatable will now be populated with values.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: It returns a table with years, not a single value.

Comment: @dearn44 can you display what your stored procedure does, so that it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Krishna. That is the part where I explain how I am calling this SP inside sql studio. THe actual SP code is just below it.

Comment: @dearn44 I ran the actual SP and it works fine. Did you try removing the last select statement and executing the code

Comment: Yes I know, it runs fine inside sql server using the query provided. It is inside my c# function that I cant get the values. The code with the `select` is never used inside c# as you can see from the code provided.