# How to return more than one SQL row data using C# using 2 reader

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

How to show multi record using condition?

only show latest record (one record not all record show in list), simply while loop diplay all record before using 1st reader.

My code is:

```
      using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                       
                        reader.Read();   //1st reader
                        string qlevel =  reader["qlevel"].ToString();
                        
                        if (qlevel == "Quick-Reply")
                        {

                            string html = "<ul>";
                              while (reader.Read())
                            {

                                string bot_respons_list = String.Format("{0}", reader["Answer"]);
                                html += "<li>" + bot_respons_list + "</li>";
                            }
                            html += "</ul>";

                            ltrMessage.Text += @"<div class='user'>  User : " + TextBox1.Text +
                              " <div class='bot'>  bot:   " + html + "  </div>  " +
                              "       </div>";
                        }
}
}
```

stored Procedure-

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[spUserResponseTest]
(
@UserRequest nvarchar(255) 
)
as
BEGIN
    Select * from QnAchatbottbl WHERE question LIKE '%' + @UserRequest + '%' 


END
```

Comment: The query to the database is only returning one value.  You may need to change the query to get more results.

Comment: it's probably bcos you only have only one row of data in the db, else you can show us your query

Comment: using stored procedure , sql return multiple row but using c# only one record show .

Comment: Aha in that case (stored procedure) keep in mind, your stored procedure should return a query result table, not a single line just denoting action succeeded. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898623/retrieve-results-of-a-stored-procedure-on-c-sharp

Comment: Can you show us the procedure?

Comment: `reader.Read();   //1st reader` should be `while(reader.Read())` and the second `while(reader.Read())` shouldn't be there